# Find distance of the nearest neighbour in a 144-dimension space

Tags: multidimensional-array, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

We are currently using a library that hashes images to 144-long arrays. We need to compare these arrays with a database of arrays (so, loads of 144-long arrays).

What would be the best way to attempt this? We tried using a KD-tree, but it doesn't yield reliable results, since the order in which elements are introduced is **important** (our database of arrays does **not** have the concept of ordering).

Comment: For KD-Trees, the order of insertion should only affect performance, but never correctness. Are you sure the KD-tree is implemented correctly?
If you need an index whose structure is independent of insertion, have a look at the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org), it is internally z-ordered.

Comment: I am not sure about that, I would have assumed it is implemented correctly. We were using http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kdt-0.2.4 for this. I will have a look at PH-Trees, thanks for the tip!